# GIT --bare com arquivos já existentes

Tags: git

Estou criando um repositório git server, para que a equipe possa comitar as alterações direto no servidor, porem alguns arquivos que estão neste server devem ser enviados, quando um user baixar o repositório. É possível fazer isso?
Na verdade o projeto já existia porem nao era usado o GIT.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, são dois passos distintos:

1. Criar o seu repositório com o `git init --bare`;
2. Inicializar o git no seu diretório de projeto existente, adicionar o repositório do passo (1) como um remote e fazer o push do seu código.